# req.body isn't picking the data from the form which is being sent through the addingTask() function to the url : '/newtask'

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js, express

```
Here is the form and addingTask() function.
<form method="GET" action="/newtask" onsubmit="addingTask()">
  <label> Today's Task: </label><br>
  <input type="text" id="task"><br>
  <button type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
<script>
  function addingTask() {
    var data = {
      task: $("#task").val(),
    }
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/newtask",
      dataType: 'JSON',
      data: data,
      success: function success(result) {
        console.log("iiiiiiiiiiiii", result);
        console.log("565656565656565");
      },
      error: function error(error) {
        console.log("sdsdsdsdsd", error);
        console.log("mmmmnnnnmmmnnn");
      }
    })
  }
</script>
```

```
   This is the route file.
   var express = require('express');
   var router = express.Router();
   const indexController = 
   require("../controllers/indexController");

   /* GET home page. */
   router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
   res.render('index', { title: 'To-Do-List' });
   });

   router.get('/newtask', indexController.createTask
   );

   module.exports = router;
```

```
   This is the controller function file.
   
   const createTask = (req, res, next) => {
   console.log(req.body);
   var variable = JSON.stringify(req.body);
   res.render('index', { title: variable });
   };

   module.exports = {          //A module means file
   createTask
   }
```

Initial Screen
https://i.stack.imgur.com/itWPX.png

After filling the form and on clicking the add button i
get empty title
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqIWf.png

I have tried changing http method to 'POST' but still
the same error occurs.

Comment: you haven't prevented the default action taken by a form submit - so what is displayed is whatever the `GET /newtask` endpoint returns

Comment: okay.. but if i change the code to this 
<form>
  <label> Today's Task: </label><br>
  <input type="text" id="task"><br>
  <button type="button" onclick="addingTask()">Add</button>
</form>
It's still shows no change

Comment: because all your code does is `console.log` ... that doesn't change the page at all

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

The "type" key inside $.ajax() should be 'POST' and also in the router file it should be router.post and finally, inside controller function file it should be res.send({data: req.body.task}); instead of res.render(index, { title: variable });